# MySQL subtract time from midnight in hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a timestamp in MySQL, "date_taken" which has yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. I want to get a time difference in hh:mm:ss format between midnight (00:00:00) and date_taken.

Eg: if "date_taken" is 2014-11-28 16:30:30, I want to get the difference from midnight, 07:30:30

I have used the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '00:00:00',date('H:i:s', strtotime('date_taken'))) * FROM `table`
```

which of course seems not to be working. I am beginner in MySQL, so please bear.

Also, this difference would be used as a reverse counter on my website.

Comment: So you want the "remaining time" to midnight?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I want for the reverse counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit cumbersome, but it works:

```
set @ft = now() -- Just for testing
select @ft
     , timediff(cast(date_add(date(@ft), interval +1 day) as datetime), @ft);
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @ft                 | timediff(cast(date_add(date(@ft), interval +1 day) as datetime), @ft) |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-11-27 18:35:33 | 05:24:27                                                              |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The explanation:

- `@ft`: Just a testing variable. Substitute it with your desired field
- `date_add(date(@ft), interval +1 day)`: Truncate the value to a date (i.e. remove the time part) and add a day
- `cast(date_add(date(@ft), interval +1 day) as datetime)` Cast the new date as a date time (e.g.: with the provided value, `cast(date_add(date(@ft), interval +1 day) as datetime)` will be `2014-11-28 00:00:00`.
- Finally, the `timediff()` thing just calculates the difference between the input value and the new date-time

Hope this helps

---

Doh!!!! A simpler solution:

```
set @ft = now() -- Just for testing
select @ft, timediff('24:00:00', time(@ft));
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| @ft                 | timediff('24:00:00', time(@ft)) |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2014-11-27 18:35:33 | 05:24:27                        |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Substitute `@ft` in the `select` with your desired value/field

(I think no explanation is needed ;) )

Comment: Amazing @Barranka. Works like a charm! I am using the second one which looks so simple.

Comment: Could we also isolate the the hh, mm and ss? I need to individually assign them different variables so that I can use them in reverse counter.

Comment: @Roland [Check the reference manual: Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Dude, kinda nicked my solution there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00','07:30:30');
+---------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF('24:00:00','07:30:30') |
+---------------------------------+
| 16:29:30                        |
+---------------------------------+

SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00','16:30:00');
+---------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF('24:00:00','16:30:00') |
+---------------------------------+
| 07:30:00                        |
+---------------------------------+
```

So, a working example...

```
 SELECT * FROM users;
 +-----+---------+---------------------+
 | uid | Version | install_time        |
 +-----+---------+---------------------+
 |   1 |       1 | 2014-11-28 04:38:41 |
 |   1 |       2 | 2014-11-28 14:50:27 |
 |   1 |       3 | 2014-11-28 17:15:05 |
 |   2 |       3 | 2014-11-28 16:07:34 |
 |   3 |       2 | 2014-11-28 12:50:42 |
 |   4 |       4 | 2014-11-28 00:55:37 |
 +-----+---------+---------------------+

 SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',TIME(install_time))x FROM users;
 +----------+
 | x        |
 +----------+
 | 19:21:19 |
 | 09:09:33 |
 | 06:44:55 |
 | 07:52:26 |
 | 11:09:18 |
 | 23:04:23 |
 +----------+
```

Comment: your answer seems to be good if I have only one value. But I have a column "date_taken" which has values in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. I used TIME(date_taken) and date_format(date_taken, '%H:%i:%s') for the time, but it returns me 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

You could try SUBTIME to subtract times, and DATE_FORMAT to set the format of each date.

e.g:

```
  SELECT SUBTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999','1 1:1:1.000002');
    -> '2007-12-30 22:58:58.999997'

  SELECT SUBTIME(DATE_FORMAT('date_taken', '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s'),DATE_FORMAT('date_taken', '%Y-%d-%m'));
```

(untested)

That should subtract a full yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss date from midnight on the same day.

date() and strtotime() are not MySQL functions - they're php functions. You can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP in the mysql query instead of strtotime(), though you'd need to make sure the timezone is the same.

Comment: Exactly. When I use UNIX_TIMESTAMP, I face timezone issues.